# Laravel 5.1 LTS laravel/installer guzzlehttp error

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

The latest `laravel/installer` cannot install the guzzlehttp dependency, which seems to be a PHP incompatibility error. Is there a workaround for installation without manually fixing guzzlehttp code?

[image: guzzlehttp]

Comment: try composer update on your server

Comment: Can you please use the guzzle tag? It's confusing as your question is the only one in guzzlehttp.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issue for Guzzle 4 on PHP 7.x. There is already a fix PR, but the tests are failing:

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/1595

I suggest you updating your Guzzle version as 4.x is already EOL.